# Почему может не срабатывать JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

почему не срабатывает у меня Jquery? Вот есть функция

```
$('.btn_act_offer').click(function() {
    var $id = $(this).data('offer-id');
    var $url = $(this).data('url');
    //var $class = $(this).hasClass('activate_offer');
    if ($(this).hasClass('activate_offer')){
        var action = 'activate';
    }else{
        var action = 'deactivate';
    }


    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: $url,
        data: { offer_id: $id, action: action},
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
               if($(this).hasClass('activate_offer')){
                   swal("Success!", data.payload, "success");
                   $(this).removeClass('activate_offer')
                       .removeClass('btn-success')
                       .addClass('btn-danger')
                       .addClass('deactivate_offer')
                       .text('Деактивировать');
                   console.log('if');
                } else {
                   swal("Success!", data.payload, "success");
                   $(this).removeClass('deactivate_offer')
                       .removeClass('btn-danger')
                       .addClass('btn-success')
                       .addClass('activate_offer')
                       .text('Активировать');

                   console.log('else');
                }
            } else {
                // for debugging
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            alert('Произошла ошибка! Обновите страницу!');
            //alert(xhr.status);
            //alert(thrownError);
        }
    })

});
```

После ajax запроса не удаляются классы и не добавляются, хотя console.log() срабатывает. Если ввожу в панели вебмастера в браузере то все работает отлично. Направте что не так, а кстати вот HTML этой кнопки:

```
<button data-offer-id="3" data-url="http://ka.local/admin/change-status-offer" class="btn btn-success activate_offer btn_act_offer">Активировать</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `this` в обработчике `success` не то, что Вы думаете.

```
if($(this).hasClass('activate_offer')){
```

---

Вот так будет работать:

```
success: (function(data) {
  ...
}).bind(this),
```

Comment: можете подсказать? Потому что подобный код с другой кнопкой отлично работает.

Comment: @rodgers Я же не вижу "подобный код". Очевидно, в нем есть принципиальное отличие от неработающего кода в вопросе.

Comment: Видимо так, спасибо помогло. А что тут делается можете пояснить?

Comment: @rodgers `bind` возвращает обертку функции, так что сама функция вызывается в контексте того, что передали в `bind`